# How do you get changed color of element after Chrome renderer emulation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, accessibility, puppeteer

Chrome has introduced an option for their renderer (in dev tools) to emulate vision deficiencies like color blindness. However these 'filters' do not change CSS or computed styles I can access through JavaScript.

Is there a way to, programmatically, get the rendered color of elements and text after applying a vision deficiency filter such as Tritanopia in Chrome?

Link to Chrome Developer update for this feature: [What's New In DevTools (Chrome 83)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/03/devtools)

I have tried:

- Accessing `Element.style` through js on page.
- Using `getComputedStyle`.
- Misc. Puppeteer methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not using Chrome dev tools or any current colour picker plugins. It appears the filter is applied completely separately to any exposed values and applied over the top of the page (easiest way to see this is to select "blurred vision" from the menu, you will see that any plugins also receive the same blur effect).

### Quick and dirty way (not programmatically)

Your best bet would be to use the [colour contrast analyser from paciello group](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastanalyser/) or a similar piece of software that exists outside the browser and takes actual pixel colour values after applying the filters.

Obviously I am aware this is not programmatically.

### Programmatically

You could build something yourself.

You would probably find [this page on colour blindness simulation in JS](http://web.archive.org/web/20081014161121/http://www.colorjack.com/labs/colormatrix/) very useful as it explains how to do transforms on RGB colours to simulate colour blindness. Then all you need to do is create a colour picker overlay (or something you can enter the hex value into and get the corresponding colour).

An alternative way to do it might be to add an [SVG colour filter that simulates colour blindness](https://www.ashleysheridan.co.uk/blog/Testing+Colour+Blindness+Effects+Online+with+SVG+Filters) to the page and then just use a [normal colour picker plugin.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorpick-eyedropper/ohcpnigalekghcmgcdcenkpelffpdolg)

Perhaps add a request for this feature as it would make life easier!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion :) However, using CSS or SVG filters don't seem to modify a value I can grab programmatically. Do you know a way to read the modified color though javascript?

Comment: the first link titled "this page on colour blindness simulation in JS" has everything you need to build your own. **There is no way to read the modified colour using JS** I am afraid due to how the colour filters are applied, the only way to achieve this would be to replicate the colour filters and then calculate the end colour so you can grab the end colour. The question really is why you need to work this out programatically as there may be a better way to achieve your end goal.

Comment: The end goal would be completely automated testing of the contrast between text and background elements even for colorblind users, on a large number of pages with a large quantity of elements to check. Currently I am only able to do this for regular sighted people at large scale.

Comment: So you would use your existing method to get the foreground and background colours. Run them through the [JS colour blindness matrix](http://web.archive.org/web/20081014161121/http://www.colorjack.com/labs/colormatrix/) to calculate the end colour for each type of colour blindness (both foreground and background) and then test it using a colour contrast formula - see [luminance formula](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/#relativeluminancedef) and [how to calculate colour contrast](https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/knowledge/colours-and-contrast/how-to-calculate/#the-formula)

Comment: Thank you so much for the links! That seems to be the way forward.

Comment: no problem, if you manage to sort something out that does this I would love to see it!